# Random even number between 10 and 50

Tags: powershell

I have seen a few sloppy ways to accomplish this but I figure someone had a simple clean method.
Just trying to generate 1 random even number between 10 and 50.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generate a random number between 5 and 25, then multiply it by 2.

```
2 * (Get-Random -Maximum 26 -Minimum 5)
```